# Why does not this table take the rowspan? Html rowspan

Tags: html, html-table, rows

I have a problem with the rowspan on a table, html the problem is that the last 4 columns the rowspan is 9 but I do not understand why it is not taking it.

[image: ProblemTable Capture]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ejemplo del uso de tablas- aprenderaprogramar.com</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <table border="2px">
      <!-- Lo cambiaremos por CSS -->
      <div class="with-left-panel" id="MainContent">
        <table border='1'>
          <tr>
            <td>Factura</td>
            <td>Cliente</td>
            <td>Total unidades</td>
            <td>Total venta</td>
            <td>Fecha</td>
            <td>No</td>
            <td>Referencia</td>
            <td>Nombre</td>
            <td>Detalle</td>
            <td>Cantidad</td>
            <td>Precio</td>
            <td>Iva</td>
            <td>Total</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td rowspan=11>Factura</td>
            <td rowspan=11>Nombre</td>
            <td rowspan=11>2</td>
            <td rowspan=11>161978</td>
            <td rowspan=11>2017-06-01 01:41:06</td>
            rowm spamn 1
            <td rowspan=1> 1</td>
            <td rowspan=1> 12501</td>
            <td rowspan=1> Leche x 25</td>
            <td>Sin Detalle </td>
            <td rowspan=1> 1</td>
            <td rowspan=1> 22686</td>
            <td rowspan=1> 19</td>
            <td rowspan=1> 26996</tr>

          <td rowspan=10> 2</td>
          <td rowspan=10> 12518</td>

          <td rowspan=10> Kit</td>

          <tr>
            <td>K2</td>
            <tr>
              <td>K3</td>
              <tr>
                <td>K4</td>
                <tr>
                  <td>K5</td>
                  <tr>
                    <td>K6</td>
                    <tr>
                      <td>K7</td>
                      <tr>
                        <td>K8</td>
                        <tr>
                          <td>K9</td>
                          <tr>
                            <td>K10</td>


                          <td rowspan=9> 1</td>
                          <td rowspan=9> 456</td>
                          <td rowspan=9> 19</td>
                          <td rowspan=9> 4567


     </tr>


        </table>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put those rowspan=9 `<td>`s (1, 456, 19, 4567) in the same row as K2.